# Wishing someone that something goes easily for them

Tags: phrasing

I'm trying to phrase a sentence in which I'm wishing that something goes easily for someone, but can't get the wording to sound right, and not awkward.

For example, someone may be studying for a test and I wish that their studying goes easy. These are the phrases I could come up with.

- I hope it goes easy for you.
- I hope the studying goes easy for you.
- I wish you the best in studying.
- I'm hoping the studying goes easily for you.
- Good luck studying. (I don't really like this one since it's a bit vague)

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. The reason this one is awkward is because OP specifically wants to sound positive about the experience of *studying*, not the outcome of the exam which follows.

In the general case of an *action*, we tend to say **I hope you enjoy your [action]**. But that's a rather odd thing to say about *studying* in this context, since OP implies it's basically an arduous task where the best one could hope for is that it shouldn't be *too* arduous.

I personally wouldn't like to use *easy* in this context because OP certainly doesn't want to encourage the person to *take it easy* - probably quite the opposite, in fact. If it's important to retain the 'easiness' concept, maybe **I hope you don't find the studying too arduous**.

I don't much like the word *studying* in this context either, so I'd suggest **I hope the revision goes well** if OP doesn't like **Good luck with...**

Comment: I particularly like "I hope you don't find the studying too arduous." It conveys an empathy that the other suggestions don't, because it recognizes that studying can be difficult.

Comment: @Kit: I can empathise with that! :-)

Comment: I like your suggestion. The only thing I would change is the word "arduous" since it's not too common of a word. Do you have any suggestions for more commonly occurring synonyms to use instead?

Comment: @Senseful: Hard, tough, trying, difficult, taxing, demanding, laborious, painful?

Comment: +1: "I hope the studying isn't too painful" sounds good to me!

Comment: @Senseful: Unless you're addressing a non-native speaker, I wouldn't worry about "arduous" being a little bit less common than some alternatives. Everyone will understand it, and [here] are 20,000+ written instances in the past century. It's a bit like using *pleasant* instead of *nice* or *good*, in that it's very slightly formal. On the other hand, "painful" is extremely informal/metaphoric in this context, and would almost always be accompanied by a wry smile. You wouldn't normally use it unless you're very close to the person you're addressing.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> **Hope everything goes smoothly for you."**

Comment: Idiot: Hah hah. Your suggestion neatly sidesteps the awkwardness of singling out the studying as opposed to the exam. Bit of a cop-out, semantically speaking, but doubtless that's what most people would actually say.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your studies go well for you.
I wish you the best with your studies.

(I find it easier to migrate the gerund to an unambiguous noun.)